# dependency error while installing docker 1.12 in rhel 7

Tags: linux, docker, rhel7

**Aim: Install latest docker (v1.12) in rhel 7 in offline mode**

- I got dependency error while installing docker 1.12 in rhel 7, and I
  tried to find those dependencies in internet but didn't found those
  dependencies except **selinux-policy rpm**.

[image]

- I tried to install after **yum update**.
- I found dependencies of docker 1.7 on internet, installed in rhel 6.7
  but could not make same way for docker 1.12 in rhel 7

**I tried below things**

- Installed docker 1.12 when system(test machine) is connected to internet and after installing docker 1.12 all dependencies will cache in **/var/cahce/yum/rhel7/** location and search for above dependencies but didn't found.
- Crated local yum repo and mounted iso file and then did **yum update**
  and tried to install docker but still give same dependencies error.
- I'm not sure how above steps are correct or right procedure, I just tired but anything didn't work.

  my production environment does not have internet connection and it has only intranet connection only.

  - Can some one provide or advice me how to solve this and how to proceed this kind of problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of surprised you can't find at least the non-docker packages here as these come from standard CentOS repositories. In general, I'd use something like:

```
# yum provides "*/<filename>"
```

e.g.

```
# yum provides "*/libsystemd.so.*"
```

This obviously won't help if you've not configured the repositories on your target system, but it's pretty easy to run a Vagrant VM and see what's required there.

```
$ vagrant init bento/centos-7.2
$ vagrant ssh
```

then follow the docs at https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/:

```
$ sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo <<-'EOF'
[dockerrepo]
name=Docker Repository
baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
EOF
```

and install it:

```
$ sudo yum install docker-engine
```

On mine, this gives:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install docker-engine
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ukhost4u.com
 * extras: mirror.vorboss.net
 * updates: mirror.vorboss.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker-engine.x86_64 0:1.12.1-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: docker-engine-selinux >= 1.12.1-1.el7.centos for package: docker-engine-1.12.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit) for package: docker-engine-1.12.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7()(64bit) for package: docker-engine-1.12.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker-engine-selinux.noarch 0:1.12.1-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package libseccomp.x86_64 0:2.2.1-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.4.2-21.el7_2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

============================================================================================================

 Package                         Arch             Version                        Repository            Size ============================================================================================================

Installing:
 docker-engine                   x86_64           1.12.1-1.el7.centos            dockerrepo            19 M Installing for dependencies:
 docker-engine-selinux           noarch           1.12.1-1.el7.centos            dockerrepo            28 k  libseccomp                      x86_64           2.2.1-1.el7                    base                  49 k  libtool-ltdl                    x86_64           2.4.2-21.el7_2                 updates               49 k

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================================

Install  1 Package (+3 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 19 M
Installed size: 79 M
```

Running that `yum provides` command I gave above shows you that e.g. `libsystemd.so*` is in the `systemd-libs` package and available in the "updates" repo .. see http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:
yum install libtool-ltdl
After this re-run installation command.
This will be done automatically, if you have "docker-ce" repository.
Good luck!